# Nginx equivalent of “cookie prefix” from HAproxy

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, haproxy

We're in the process of migrating from HAProxy to nginx. With HAProxy, we use something like this

```
cookie SESSIONID prefix
server websvr1 192.168.1.71:80 weight 1 maxconn 512 cookie 1 check
server websvr2 192.168.1.72:80 weight 1 maxconn 512 cookie 2 check
```

This will allow client to send cooke like `1~SESSIONID` and HAProxy will strip the prefix.

Can Nginx achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

Yes but only in the commercial version as documented in the nginx doc.
https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#sticky

Here a short example

```
upstream backend {
  server backend1.example.com;
  server backend2.example.com;

  sticky cookie srv_id expires=1h domain=.example.com path=/;
}
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)